# Django: Restrict static folder access to non logged-in users

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to restrict those users, who directly hit on a absolute static image url path(www.xyz.com/static/img/sam.png) in browser and access it.

I tried with the following django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/

But this will block those images which are there in login page also(before valid user is authenticated).

Is there any other efficient way to do restrict **non logged-in** users?

**EDIT:**
I had referred to this [Django: Serving Media Behind Custom URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687957/django-serving-media-behind-custom-url) but it is related to nginx and not apache.
And also there is a difference b/w static and media content. My question is related to just static content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Serving Media Behind Custom URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687957/django-serving-media-behind-custom-url)

Comment: @creimers that is for media files. I am asking about static related files!

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Put the public files in one location and the private files in another location. Tell apache to serve the public files freely, and require authentication for the private files.

Comment: @creimers The same difference which django has defined in the docs, Media = mp3, mp4, etc;  Static= img, css, js

Comment: @HåkenLid Yes that was my last option. Just wanted to know if there was any other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41107317/3872951) by just routing `static` url request to your own view (it tries to use sendfile extension available in almost all web servers) or use django [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/), whitenoise  uses sendfile api which is server independent ( whether you are using nginx or apache) and production ready, extend the whitenoise `middleware` and add your checking there for file restriction, a `sample` code will be

```
  from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
  from whitenoise.middleware import WhiteNoiseMiddleware
  # this is a sample code, you can change for your use case
  class ProtectedStaticFileMiddleware(WhiteNoiseMiddleware):
        def process_request(self, request):
            # check user authentication
            if condition_met(request):
               return super(WhiteNoiseMiddleware, self).process_request(request)
            # condition false
            return HttpResponseForbidden("you are not authorized")
```

NOTE: Serving files directly ( large files ) using python file chunks api is not a good idea when you are in production ( ideas like file.read() or FileResponse)

Comment: Thanks. Will check the same.