# How can I set my static files just can access by authenticated user in Django

Tags: django

I want to protect my static file from unauthorized user, How should I do in Django?
Ex:

```
/static/public/ : can access by anyone
/static/private/: just fror authorized user
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Serving Media Behind Custom URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687957/django-serving-media-behind-custom-url)

Comment: Thank @IakovosBelonias, I'm want to protect not only files in the folder, but also in the sub folders, and don't know the folder struct.