# how to make an .mp4 file inaccessible on the public side

Tags: video, joomla, mp4

I'm writing to ask you for help. I manage a video site, my interest is to make an .mp4 file private, let me explain better.

Inside my web space there are videos that are managed with yendif video player since I use Joomla as CMs. Up to this point the problem does not arise because the user who needs to see the video must be logged in to do so.

The problem arises instead if the customer knows the direct link to the mp4 file for example ([www.miosito.com/folder/folder/video.mp4](http://www.miosito.com/folder/folder/video.mp4)) in this case the user can download it.

I tried two different solutions.

1. Modify the group permissions by removing the check with filezilla for reading. By doing so, the registered user cannot see the film.
2. Privacy directory present in cpanel, but I excluded this because you need to set a user and password to see the videos.

Turning to you, is there a way to make the video not accessible on the public side and at the same time used for viewing by the logged in user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If someone has the link, they have the link. Without making unique urls for your content, and tying that to a user via some identifier like IP address or email address, you cannot prevent them sharing a link.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply but I can't understand what you mean. Would you be so kind to help me understand better, thank you

Comment: @Cristian _"If the customer knows the direct link to the mp4 file"_ then make sure this part doesn't happen. Being logged in or not is irrelevant. A possible solution is to use a script file (written in PHP, Python, C# or whatever your server accepts) to **serve the video file as a stream**. For example you can use `src="myscript.php"` in a `<video>` tag. The tag will try to access that file so the script kicks into action and return bytes from the real video link. The customer only sees `<video src="myscript.php" >` and will never know it is coming from `miosito.com/folder/folder/video.mp4)`.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately, creating a php file that generates all this is really difficult for me, which is why I'm turning to you experts.
I also use Yendif video player for Joomla which are in html5 format where the registered user can see them but as I told you, I realized that these videos are stored in a folder, if the user knows the link he can download them.
Thanks again for your wonderful support.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do so is to host the mp4 file in a private folder (not accessible from the web through an .htaccess file), and then only serve that file to authenticated users through a PHP script. [Here's a quick function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2690263/916491) (but can easily be translated to PHP) on how to do it.