# django-cbv serve password protected static content

Tags: python, django, static

For every user in my django application, I generate a static .ical file which I would like to serve. Is there a CBV for that and which method would I overwrite?
As all of my views are class based I' d rather not use a function-based view with a `HttpResponse` and a `@auth_required` decorator according to this:
[Django: Serving a Download in a Generic View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681338/django-serving-a-download-in-a-generic-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inherit from the `View` model and override the view method.

```
class ICalDownload(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # return your response just like you would in a function view.
```

If you want to protect the view, I like to use [django-braces](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces). Otherwise, you need to use `method_decorator` on the dispatch method:

```
@method_decorator(auth_required)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(ICalDownload, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

At this point, a function based view might be a little simpler, but like you, I like to always use class based views.